# What are the Wikipedia Pages for these Kangyur titles

Tags: mahayana, sutras, tibetan-buddhism, texts, tibetan

Not knowing Tibetan or having access to a wide array of sources, I am using the (Tibetan script) Kangyur from [these](http://www.asianclassics.org/tibetan/). The table of contents is [here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/386a51710e8403c3774e2f3b7e105fbb) pretty much. After converting their Excel file to a CSV, I was able to find at least the English titles for "The Perfection of Wisdom in X Lines" series.

For example:

- `KL00012-001(eTB)`
- *'PHAGS PA SHES RAB KYI PHA ROL TU PHYIN PA BRGYAD STONG PA*
- **འཕགས་པ་ཤེས་རབ་ཀྱི་ཕ་རོལ་ཏུ་ཕྱིན་པ་བརྒྱད་སྟོང་པ།**
- *The Exalted Perfection of Wisdom in 8,000 Lines (Arya Ashta Sahasrika Prajna Paramita)*

Searching Google for the Sanskrit Romanization (I'm guessing), such as "*Arya Ashta Sahasrika Prajna Paramita*" yields **no exact matches** (no matter what romanization from what CSV line I search, I get no results). Google returns [Prajnaparamita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prajnaparamita) as the first result, which is *correct* ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ no idea how Google is doing that. It is technically correct in this case, even though there is not a direct text match between `Prajnaparamita` and `Prajna Paramita`, though, well, I guess it's pretty much exact. They get other ones with less similarity correct as well, at least the general category (that may have not been the best example). However, "*Arya Ashta Sahasrika*" returns nothing, I don't even know what that means (I don't know Tibetan or Sanskrit today).

Luckily I have spent hours on THLib to know that there is a document with the exact same Tibetan script title (འཕགས་པ་ཤེས་རབ་ཀྱི་ཕ་རོལ་ཏུ་ཕྱིན་པ་བརྒྱད་སྟོང་པ།) [here](http://www.thlib.org/encyclopedias/literary/canons/kt/catalog.php#cat=kt/d/0013/text/v033p1b). So that confirms -- *in this case* -- that the Kangyur "*Perfection of Wisdom in 8,000 Lines*" from asianclassics.org is correct, it matches something else on the web at least.

But searching for other Tibetan texts on Wikipedia returns language/orthography that is completely different from these two sites (asianclassics.org and thlib.org vs. wikipedia.org). For example, Wikipedia has a nice simple page called [Diamond Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_Sutra) and even goes so far as to write out the Sanskrit name *Vajracchedikā Prajñāpāramitā Sūtra*, using *some* romanization system which I am not familiar with. Looking back in the asianclassics.org [CSV](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/386a51710e8403c3774e2f3b7e105fbb) I made, there's no exact matches for those words, but there is **Vajra** in a few places, which leads to **Vajrachedaka**, which is pretty close to the Wikipedia **Vajracchedikā**. Again, not knowing Sanskrit or Tibetan, I am left guessing if they are the same.

1. **Vajracchedikā Prajñāpāramitā Sūtra**
2. Arya **Vajrachedaka** Nama **Prajna Paramita** Mahayana **Sutra**

**Seems like it could be the same thing.** I'm not sure though.

Needless to say, this is my approach. I want to find some of the good/classic/standard/interesting/long *Tibetan script* texts in the Kangyur, based on what I've seen on Wikipedia, but I am not sure I am finding them correctly. Given that THLib's site is broken on most of the documents, we are left with asianclassics.org. So I wanted to ask, what are the Wikipedia titles for these asianclassics.org titles, (from the [CSV](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/386a51710e8403c3774e2f3b7e105fbb))?

- KL00001-001(eTB),'DUL BA GZHI 1,འདུལ་བ་གཞི་།,"Foundation of Vowed Morality, Part 1 (Vinaya Vastu 1)",༡  འདུལ་བ།/ཀ།
- KL00007-111(eTB),'DUL BA GZHUNG DAM PA 1,འདུལ་བ་གཞུང་དམ་པ་།,"The Perfect Classic on Vowed Morality, Part 1 (Vinaya Uttara Grantha B, 1)",༡  འདུལ་བ།/ན།
- KL00001-002(eTB),'DUL BA GZHI 2,འདུལ་བ་གཞི་།,"Foundation of Vowed Morality, Part 2 (Vinaya Vastu 2)",༡  འདུལ་བ།/ཁ།
- KL00003-001(eTB),'DUL BA RNAM PAR 'BYED PA 1,འདུལ་བ་རྣམ་པར་འབྱེད་པ་།,"The Divisions of Vowed Morality, Part 1 (Vinaya Vibhangga 1)",༡  འདུལ་བ།/ཅ།
- MDO,འཕགས་པ་བསྐལ་པ་བཟང་པོ་པ་ཞེས་བྱ་བ་ཐེག་པ་ཆེན་པོའི་མདོ།,"An Exalted Sutra of the Greater Way entitled The Book of the Eon of Good Fortune"" (Arya Bhadra Kalpika Nama Mahayana Sutra)""",༡༠  མདོ་མང་།/ཀ།
- KL00133(eTB),'PHAGS PA DA LTAR GYI SANGS RGYAS MNGON SUM DU BZHUGS PA'I TING NGE 'DZIN CES BYA BA THEG PA CHEN PO'I MDO,འཕགས་པ་ད་ལྟར་གྱི་སངས་རྒྱས་མངོན་སུམ་དུ་བཞུགས་པའི་ཏིང་ངེ་འཛིན་ཅེས་བྱ་བ་ཐེག་པ་ཆེན་པོའི་མདོ།,An Exalted Sutra of the Greater Way entitled The Meditation of the Buddha Who is Directly Present Now(Arya Pratyutpanne Buddha Sammukha Avasthita Samadhi Nama Mahayana Sutra),༡༠  མདོ་མང་།/ཐ།
- KL00134(eTB),'PHAGS PA BSOD NAMS THAMS CAD BSDUS PA'I TING NGE 'DZIN CES BYA BA THEG PA CHEN PO MDO,འཕགས་པ་བསོད་ནམས་ཐམས་ཅད་བསྡུས་པའི་ཏིང་ངེ་འཛིན་ཅེས་བྱ་བ་ཐེག་པ་ཆེན་པོ་མདོ།,"An Exalted Sutra of the Greater Way entitled A Meditation which Incorporates Every Virtue(Arya Sarva Punye Samuchaya Samadhi Mahayana Sutra)""",༡༠  མདོ་མང་།/ཐ།
  KL00135(eTB),RDO RJE'I TING NGE 'DZIN GYI CHOS KYI YI GE,རྡོ་རྗེའི་ཏིང་ངེ་འཛིན་གྱི་ཆོས་ཀྱི་ཡི་གེ,A Word of Teaching on the Diamond Meditation (no Sanskrit),༡༠  མདོ་མང་།/ཐ།
- KL00136(eTB),'PHAGS PA KHYE'U BZHI'I TING NGE 'DZIN CES BYA BA THEG PA CHEN PO'I MDO,འཕགས་པ་ཁྱེའུ་བཞིའི་ཏིང་ངེ་འཛིན་ཅེས་བྱ་བ་ཐེག་པ་ཆེན་པོའི་མདོ།,"An Exalted Sutra of the Greater Way entitled The Meditation of the Four Youths"" (Arya Chatur Daraka Samadhi Mahayana Sutra)""",༡༠  མདོ་མང་།/ཐ།
- KL00137(eTB),'PHAGS PA TING NGE 'DZIN MCHOG DAM PA,འཕགས་པ་ཏིང་ངེ་འཛིན་མཆོག་དམ་པ།,"The Exalted Most Supreme of Meditations"" (Arya Samadhyagrottama)""",༡༠  མདོ་མང་།/ཐ།
- KL00138(eTB),'PHAGS PA 'DUS PA CHEN PO RIN PO CHE TOG GI GZUNGS ZHES BYA BA THEG PA CHEN PO'I MDO,འཕགས་པ་འདུས་པ་ཆེན་པོ་རིན་པོ་ཆེ་ཏོག་གི་གཟུངས་ཞེས་བྱ་བ་ཐེག་པ་ཆེན་པོའི་མདོ།,"An Exalted Sutra of the Greater Way entitled The Great Gathering, the Secret Formula of the Tip of Jewel"" (Arya Mahasannipata Ratna Ketu Dharani NamaMahayana Sutra)""",༡༠  མདོ་མང་།/ཐ།
- KL00139(eTB),'PHAGS PA RDO RJE'I SNYING PO'I GZUNGS ZHES BYA BA THEG PA CHEN PO'I MDO,འཕགས་པ་རྡོ་རྗེའི་སྙིང་པོའི་གཟུངས་ཞེས་བྱ་བ་ཐེག་པ་ཆེན་པོའི་མདོ།," An Exalted Sutra of the Greater Way entitled The Secret Formula of the Essence of Diamond"" (Arya Vajra Manda Nama Dharani Mahayana Sutra)""",༡༠  མདོ་མང་།/ཐ།
- KL00140(eTB),'PHAGS PA SGO MTHA' YAS PA SGRUB PA ZHES BYA BA'I GZUNGS,འཕགས་པ་སྒོ་མཐའ་ཡས་པ་སྒྲུབ་པ་ཞེས་བྱ་བའི་གཟུངས།,"An Exalted Secret Formula entitled, The Accomplishment of Infinite Goals"" (Arya Ananta Mukha Sadhaka Nama Dharani)""",༡༠  མདོ་མང་།/ཐ།
- ...

Specifically, in the CSV, I am looking for the various [Mahayana Sutras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahayana_sutras).

1. Aṣṭasāhasrikā Prajñāpāramitā Sūtra
2. Infinite Life Sutra
3. Lotus Sutra
4. Pure Land sutras
5. Akṣobhyatathāgatasyavyūha Sūtra
6. Ugraparipṛcchā Sūtra
7. Mañjuśrīparipṛcchā Sūtra
8. Drumakinnararājaparipṛcchā Sūtra
9. Śūraṅgama Samādhi Sūtra
10. Bhadrapāla Sūtra
11. Ajātaśatrukaukṛtyavinodana Sūtra
12. Kāśyapaparivarta Sūtra
13. Lokānuvartana Sūtra

Or any other standard/key sutras which would be interesting.

The main thing is, I guess, what are the top 10 or 20 sutras in that CSV, and what are their "common" names so I can find out more info on them on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

I found most of the texts on Rigpa:

[Aṣṭasāhasrikā Prajñāpāramitā Sūtra](https://archive.org/details/bdrc-W1KG22205/page/n2)

[Lotus Sutra](https://www.tbrc.org/#!rid=W22084)

[Pure Land sutras](https://www.tbrc.org/#!rid=O00EGS1014793%7CO00EGS10147938LS10774$W4615)

[Ugraparipṛcchā Sūtra](https://www.tbrc.org/#!rid=O4JW5431%7CO4JW54314JW25592$W1KG4598)

[Mañjuśrīparipṛcchā Sūtra](https://www.tbrc.org/#!rid=O1VI2%7CO1VI21KG48376$W1PD127393)

[Śūraṅgama Samādhi Sūtra](https://www.tbrc.org/#!rid=W1KG13760)

[Kāśyapaparivarta Sūtra](https://www.tbrc.org/#!rid=O1VI2%7CO1VI21KG48340$W1PD127393)

[Lokānuvartana Sūtra](https://www.tbrc.org/#!rid=O1VI2%7CO1VI21KG48523$W1PD127393)